# Qur'an claims Muhammad (saw) performed no supernatural miracles?

Tags: quran, hadith, prophet-muhammad

Quran claims that Muhammad (saw) performed no supernatural, verifiable miracles apart from the inspiration that he received.

**The unbelievers say, 'Why has a sign (ayatun) not been sent down upon him from his Lord?' Thou art ONLY a warner, and a guide to every people. S. 13:7**

**They also say, 'Why has no sign (ayatun) been sent down upon him from his Lord?' Say: 'Surely God is able to send down a sign (ayatan), but most of them know not.' S. 6:37**

Does this contradict with the hadith literature that narrates authentic reports of Prophet Muhammad (saw) performing miracles? For example, the splitting of the moon, spitting in the food so it feeds many people, water flowing from his fingers, spitting in the eye to heal it? etc etc

Answer (score 1):

No. It in no way contradicts the Sunnah. The Qur'an verses you referenced only suggest he had not brought any other miracles **at that point**, but does it say anywhere that he would never do so? No. In fact, Allah (ﷻ) said:

> If We willed, We could send down to them from the sky a sign for which their necks would remain humbled. [Qur'an (26:4)].

Allah (ﷻ) delayed bringing other miracles to them, out of His Wisdom. Ibn Kathir  رحمه الله  mentions:

> "Certainly, Allah is able to send an Ayah (sign). But, He decided out of His wisdom to delay that, because if He sends an Ayah of their liking and they still do not believe, this will hasten their punishment as with the previous nations" [Tafsir Ibn Kathir].

Splitting of the moon (also referenced in the Qur'an), food multiplication, water multiplication, physical healing, etc.. are all authentic miracles which he had performed thereafter during his Prophethood. Reported by numerous different people from numerous different chains.